# Does "mad" has the meaning "a lot"?

Tags: meaning

I'm watching [a short Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsbVTPftcgs) and someone posted this comment.

> After many years of watching Zatoichi films and the show. I'm stumped that this is only a short instead of a full film. I would pay mad money to see a full movie of ZVP. Brings me back to the days of watching crazy but awesome Japanese flicks of the bygone era.

Does *pay mad money* mean *pay a lot of money*? I can't find this meaning in the dictionary. I got the meaning from this translator: https://translate.sogou.com/text
I also checked other translator (like https://www.deepl.com/translator), which doesn't suggest "a lot".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a colloquial use of "mad" as an intensifier, like "I've got mad skills" or "the boss level is mad hard" (see [definition 9 in this entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mad)). Don't be confused, there's also a [phrase "*mad money*"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mad%20money) meaning "money to be spent however you want," but that's not the meaning that's being used here.

Comment: You might consider linking a dictionary definition, like this one: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mad.

Comment: @Juhasz I think you'll find that I did...

Comment: Sorry, I meant a definition of *mad*, not *mad money*.

Comment: @Juhasz Ah, thanks!

Comment: I think there is an additional possible nuance with 'mad money' - 'mad' being a synonym of 'crazy'. In the UK at least we can say e.g. 'I paid crazy money for that used car', or 'my brother-in-law is paid crazy money for what he does'. An insane amount of money. Like (in my opinion) the crazy prices people are willing to pay for Apple products.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sure, it could be an a propos choice for that reason, but it's also thrown around as a generic intensifier. The M-W entry mentions "mad respect"; "mad props" is common. Analogous to New England (and elsewhere) use of "wicked," as in "wicked good."